# How to move posts from a website to another without hurting SEO?

Tags: seo, migration

Think about merging two websites A and B. A is a popular website and B is a startup like one. All of the posts on B will be republished on A and posts will be deleted from B.

So here is my question, How can we do such migration without loosing SEO and hurting the value of website A on the search engines?
Will it be thought as a copy version by search engines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the transition as seamless as possible, [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) each page from the *old* B site url, to its new location in the *new* A site url.

Comment: Redirecting whole B to A's homepage is a bad idea?

Comment: Yes you redirect the whole domain, but not everything to the homepage, that will harm your rankings. You redirect old to new... i.e `exampleB.com/cars/` to `exampleA.com/cars/`, `exampleB.com/` to `exampleA.com/`

Comment: and if there is no exact match try to redirect to the most similar page / piece of information for the user

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that URL for posts is the exact match between two domains, and then use 301 [permanent] redirects, and place it in domainA root folder.

For example, to redirect:

```
domainA.com/path/post1.html
domainA.com/path/post2.html
```

to

```
domainB.com/path/post1.html
domainA.com/path/post2.html
```

Create .htaccess file [if you are using Apache] in domainA root folder with instruction:

```
# 301 redirect all request from domainA to domainB
Redirect 301 / http://domainB.com/
```

This will 301 redirect all requests from domainA to appropriate URLs on domainB.